# Print selected value from SQL to textbox VB6

Tags: sql, vb6

I am trying to print the selected value from a query in VB6 this is my code

```
dim query as string
dim stsstring as string
dim rs as adobd.recordset
query = "select status from x where y='"& randomString &"'"
set rs = mainmodule.dbutils.dbconnection.connection.execute(query)
set rs = nothing
stsstring = rs.fields("status")
msgbox stsstring
```

I get error here

```
stsstring = rs.fields("status")
```

> Object variable or with block variable not set

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You've set rs to nothing before trying to read the status field from it. Re-order your code to read:

```
'...
stsstring = rs.fields("status")
set rs = nothing
msgbox stsstring
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of the below work, but to be completely on the safe side:

```
set rs = mainmodule.dbutils.dbconnection.connection.execute(query)
if not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) then
   rs.MoveFirst
   Do While Not rs.EOF
      If Not IsNull(rs("status").value)
         stsstring = rs("status").value
         Debug.Print stsstring
      Else
         Debug.Print "Column 'status' is NULL."
      End If
      rs.MoveNext
   Loop
end if

If Not rs Is Nothing Then
   If rs.State > adStateClosed Then
      Call rs.Close()
   End If
   Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

An easy way to circumvent the `If Not IsNull()` condition for strings is to use `stsstring = vbNullString & rs("status").value`